# How to login a Webcrawler using the Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, authentication, web-crawler, httpclient

I'm trying to write a crawler for a browser game using the Apache HttpClient 4.5.12 for Java. Currently, I`m stuck at the login part. I decided to use the Apache CredentialsProvider, hoping to be able to easily login the crawler so he can do his buissnes. But, sadly, it doesn't work. Maybe my way to login the crawler does not work, maybe my code is wrong or maybe the server doesn't support what I'm trying. Don't get me wrong webcrawlers work in the game, a few other players use one, too. But back ot my problem, here is my code:

```
public void clientCredentialsVersuch(){
    CredentialsProvider cp = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope("https://www.ag-spiel.de/index.php?section=login", AuthScope.ANY_PORT);
    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("UserName" ,"PassWord");
    cp.setCredentials(authScope, credentials);

    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
    clientBuilder = clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(cp);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://www.ag-spiel.de/index.php?section=start");
    System.out.println(httpGet.getMethod());
    try {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The authenticaion magic is set to happen untill the HttpGet declaraion, as the stuff afterwards is only there to check if my try worked. Unfortenatly, the website just rederects me to the "You must be loged in to do this" page.

Is my way completly wrong? Is it better to go a completly other way? Or did I just made a small mistake? Thanks for your help!

Comment: In order to login as a normal user, you have to use libraries do so, something like puppeteer (JS Lib), or jaunt (https://jaunt-api.com/) or silinium (https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/), these libraries give you access to take actions on the web page as if you are a normal user opening it.

Comment: Thanks. I now use selenium to let the user loggin manually and then the crawler takes over again. I now have new difficulties but they don't belong to this question anymore.